# Dont find any solution, maps in android v2 dont shows up

Tags: android

I have seen a lot of posts, but when I pass the .apk project to a friend, my friend cannot see the maps.  It only shows the +- arrows and a gray background. On my phone and tablet it works fine, but on his phone it does not.

Can help me with this, or pass me a link to a similar problem?

Comment: There are so many reasons why this could not be working... Out of curiosity, did you check that his phone supports the same version os maps as yours?

Comment: How you check that? He have the google play service like me

Comment: If so you shouldn't pass him the apk file. You should have him download it from the market.

Comment: This is a test application, not a commercial app. Can not pass this if is not in the market?

Comment: If it's a test application, then you're not sending the right deliberables/redistributables/whatever it's called by the Android development community. Check the way you're packaging the file. Maybe your phone has some dependencies installed that his doesn't.

Comment: Ok, also i pass the proyect to him, and dont works too. He create your  API Key, with his account and the maps dont shows up...

Comment: No, dont use the GPS in this application

Answer (score 1):

make sure your maps api key is setup correctly.  You probably have a missing mapsapi key or an invalid one.

Comment: try researching stuff here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application

I've seen this behaviour due to a bad api key.

Comment: Has something to do, that im from argentina and the other guy is frm Ecuador, or not?